# How did Spivak come to this equality?

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-explanation, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

This is an excerpt from Calculus Answers in regards to showing that the inequality $M_i' - m_i \leq M_i - m_i$ (where $M_i, m_i$ define the $\inf$ and $\sup$ of any interval when computing Riemann sums).
[image]

I'm uncertain how he came to the equality of $M_i'$ and $M_i$; wouldn't the inequality $-m_i \leq M_i$ mean $M_i' \leq M_i$? Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: You didn't specify how $M_i'$ and $m_i'$ are defined.

Comment: Christ, Mi' and mi' are defined as the sup and inf of the function |f| (where Mi and mi are the sup and inf of f)

Comment: Either $M_i' = M_i$ or $M_i' = m_i'$. But $-m_i \le M_i$, so either $-m_i<M_i$ and then $M_i' = M_i$, or else $-m_i = M_i$, in which case $M_i = M_i' = -m_i$.